# How to handle user using website before javascript fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and I found out that is better to declare your javascript file at the bottom of the page, but one of the con of this is sometimes the javascript is not fully loaded when the user started to use the page, how can I handle this sort of thing?

Comment: `when the user started to use the page` - use in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found out that is better to declare your javascript file at the bottom of the page

This is definitely not true. In most JavaScript tutorials you will see that script tags are located in `<head>`, preferably with `async` set. Scripts are also often uglified and combined into a single script file to minimize the number of HTTP requests and file size.

> Sometimes the javascript is not fully loaded when the user started to use the page

Many websites are built to look nice even when the script hasn't been loaded with placeholders. Take a look at [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) for some inspiration on how to create such design.

In cases where the script *has* to be loaded for the site to function, try displaying a loading screen or a splash screen.